$AM+BN$ attains its miminum

In Euclidean space, given $2$ parallel lines $d,k$ and a line $m$ that
intersects $d,k$. Let $A,B$ lie in the half-plane that does not
contain $k$, with the boundary being the line $d$. Find $M\in k, N\in
 d$ s.t $MN//m$ and $AM+BN$ attains its miminum.


At first, I construct parallelogram $MNBC$. It's easy to see that $C$ is fixed.
We also have $AM+BN=AM+MC\geq AC$, which is constant! But unluckily, the equality does not hold! So I can't find $M,N$ if I proceed this way. Could someone have anyway to find such $M,N$? I would be very appreciated if someone could help me. Thanks in advance !

On the one hand, I considered downvoting your posted question because I think that the posting is missing several details, with respect to this article on MathSE protocol.  However, despite this, I decided to go the other way, and upvote (+1) your posting, because you took a very difficult problem to present, discussed it very clearly, and diagrammed it very well.

Hint: try to reflect point $C$ in line $k$ (let's say that would be point $C'$) and note that $AM+MC = AM + MC'$

@AntonGrudkin Very clever way to fix my solution! Thanks
